# How to start the grpc server when definitions are in a module

Tags: dagster

My project structure looks like this:

- /definitions (for all dagster python definitions)

  - `__init__.py`
  - repositories.py
  - /exchangerates

    - pipelines.py
    - ...
  - ...
- workspace.yaml

I've tried running the grpc server using various methods, especially the following (started in project root):

- `dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -f definitions/repositories.py`
- `dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -m definitions`
- `dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -m definitions.repositories`

The first command yields the following error:

> dagster.core.errors.DagsterImportError: Encountered ImportError: `attempted relative import with no known parent package` while importing module repositories from file C:\Users\Klaus\PycharmProjects\dagsterexchangerates\definitions\repositories.py. Consider using the module-based options `-m` for CLI-based targets or the `python_package` workspace.yaml target.

The second and third command yield the following error:

> (stacktrace comes before this)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definitions'

How can this be solved?

EDIT:
I've uploaded the current version of the example I'm working on to GitHub: https://github.com/kstadler/dagster-exchangerates

EDIT2:
Reflected changes in directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry about the trouble - there are a couple of options here to get your server running.

To get it working with the '-f' option, the relative imports need to be replaced with absolute imports. That would look like this:

```
-from .pipelines import exchangerates_pipline
-from .partitions import year_partition_set
+from definitions.pipelines import exchangerates_pipline
+from definitions.partitions import year_partition_set
```

(This is the same error you would get if you tried to run `python definitions/repositories.py` directly).

I'm still digging into why exactly the third '-m' option isn't working the way I'd expect it to. Curiously the following command seems to work for me which should be close to identical:

```
python -m dagster.grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -m definitions.repositories
```

Incidentally, your example contains a workspace.yaml that should cause dagit and other Dagster processes to automatically start up the gRPC server for you for that module - so depending on your goal you may not need to run `dagster api grpc` yourself at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Changing to absolute imports worked, the grpc server is running now. Unfortunately I've run into another problem when applying this to my docker compose configuration (all the services run, but when I'm starting a run in dagit I get a Bad Request ("invalid reference format") error from docker)